# Oracle Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore conflicting dependency on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, nuget error in .NET8

Tags: entity-framework-core

Upgraded a solution to .NET 8. Facing a challenge with Oracle EF Core. There appears to be a conflict:

> Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore requires Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 7.0.3 && < 8.0.0)

Note: less than `8.0.0`

This conflicts with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` that requires `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 8.0.0)`, note greater than (or equal to) 8.0.0.

The error is:

> Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 8.0.0 directly to project TheTechZap.ZxvTools.Database.Oracle_LVQ5XG to resolve this issue.
>
> Corp.App.Database.Oracle_LVQ5XG -> Corp.App.Database.Common_YYTQZR -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 8.0.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 8.0.0)
> Corp.App.Database.Oracle_LVQ5XG -> Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.12 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 7.0.3 && < 8.0.0).      > Database.Oracle
> C:\src\Database.Oracle\Database.Oracle.csproj

This is a fragment from the `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.120" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.21.12" />
```

##### Background:

- Need both SQL Server and Oracle Entity Framework Core packages in the same project structure because both database vendors are used in the same app
- The project is packaged as a nuget, when this nuget is consumed, the errors occur

##### Solution?

Is there a way to solve this issue:

- now without awaiting for Oracle to release EFCore 8 packages.
- without downgrading to EFCore 7x
- somehow using both EFCore 7 and 8 in the same project structure (as in no changes to project structures)

PS: we tried adding this line which fails:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="8.0.0" />
```

with this error:

> Error downloading
> 'Corp.App.MyPackage' - Unable to
> find a version of 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationaI' that is compatible with 'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 7.21.12 constraint:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ReIationaI 7.0.3 & < 8.0.0)'.

Comment: It's because Oracle haven't made a version for EF core 8 yet. There is nothing to do, before they make a new version.  https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/328

Comment: excellent thanks @Michael, you are right. In the meantime is there a workaround that does not invovle downgrading to EFCore 7x?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry. Well, I actually think that it is just a warning, so you could just try it

Comment: you're right about it being a nuget warning, on exectution, the errors fire, causing a halt..!

Comment: If maybe a preview version of EF would temporariliy suffice, I can confirm that I can use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational:8.0.0-preview.3.23174.2` with `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore:7.21.11`

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thanks @baouss, I will give that a try

Answer (score 2):

Note that Oracle's EF Core 8 is now generally available as of December 7th, 2023. Installing this version of the package will solve the dependency issue with EF Core 8 and its packages.

Latest version of the package is [available on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore)